# Why does the console controller behave differently than the web controller? (Yii2)

Tags: php, cron, yii2, console

I have a script like this:

```
$timeNow = new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $interval = new \DateInterval('PT'. Yii::$app->params['intervalMinForDescicionIssue'] .'M');
    $timeCorrect = $timeNow->sub($interval);
    $issues = Issue::find()
        ->where(['between', 'createdDate', $timeCorrect->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), date("Y-m-d H:i:s")])
        ->all();

    foreach ($issues as $issue) {

        $issue->countMin++;

        if($issue->countMin >= Yii::$app->params['intervalMinForIssuePrice']){

            $issue->price++;
            $issue->countMin = 0;

        }

        $issue->save();
```

If to launch it through actionTest in SiteController all is ok.
If run through the console on the cron every minute in basic/commands/CronController, for some reason it updates the data not in all rows of the table, but strictly in 6 rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The console controller does not behave differently from the web controller. The problem is setting the time for cronjob for one minute. Try setting the time for 5 minutes and see how many rows get executed. The number will probably increase

Answer (score 0):

You can have a different config (e.g. params / params-local).